# RenderView in My service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new of symfony world.
I want to use render inside my service, but I got this error

> Call to undefined method renderView

I know that renderView is shortcut of

```
/**
 * Returns a rendered view.
 *
 * @param string $view       The view name
 * @param array  $parameters An array of parameters to pass to the view
 *
 * @return string The rendered view
 */
public function renderView($view, array $parameters = array())
{
    return $this->container->get('templating')->render($view, $parameters);
}
```

But I don't know what I have to Injection in my service. I know even that with `php app/console container:debug` command I Can see all my services available, but I don't know how can take/choose the correct

**update**

I tried to add

```
arguments: [@mailer,@templating]
```

but I got `ServiceCircularReferenceException`

**UPDATE**

I changed my service.yml with

```
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

and even my service

```
$email = $this->service_container->get('mailer');
$twig = $this->service_container->get('templating');
```

for use service Mail (swift) and render.

I don't think that it's best solution. I'd like to injection Only `mailer` and `templating`

**UPDATE After Jason's answer**
I'm using Symfony 2.3

my services.yml

```
services:
    EmailService:
        class: %EmailService.class%
        arguments:  [@mailer,@templating,%EmailService.adminEmail%]
```

I got this `ServiceCircularReferenceException`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are correct about `renderView()`, it's only a shortcut for Controllers.  When using a service class and inject the templating service, all you have to do is change your function to `render()` instead.  So instead of

```
return $this->renderView('Hello/index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
```

you would use

```
return $this->render('Hello/index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
```

**Update from Olivia's response:**

If you are getting circular reference errors, the only way around them is to inject the whole container.  It's not considered best practice but it sometimes cannot be avoided.  When I have to resort to this, I still set my class variables in the constructor so I can act as if they were injected directly. So I will do:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class MyClass()
{
    private $mailer;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->mailer = $container->get('mailer');
        $this->templating = $container->get('templating');
    }
    // rest of class will use these services as if injected directly
}
```

Side note, I just tested my own standalone service in Symfony 2.5 and did not receive a circular reference by injecting the mailer and templating services directly.

Comment: this is clear, but if i Inject `[@mailer,@templating]` i have to inject All the container.

Comment: What type of service are you creating?  Is it a standalone or is it a listener to another event?  You shouldn't get a circular reference error with just mailer and templating unless you are listening on an event that already injects those.  I'm guessing you're using the templating to render a template that is used for your email.

Comment: it's a simple service that create email and render emailTemplate

Comment: What version of Symfony are you running? I know in the past the templating environment caused circular references more frequently because it was dependent on many other services, but I've injected both the mailer and templating into my services without a problem.  Can you update your question to show the full configuration of your service (the yml file part)?

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Jason, maybe Symfony 2.3 have this issue. In your code, why you use ContainerInterface before variable? what Service you are inject? `service_container` ?

Comment: Yes when you inject `arguments: [@service_container]` it is of type `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface`; I use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to make sure the proper container service is being injected

Comment: How can you know that `service_container` is `ContainerInterface` in file php? the name is different...maybe it's stupid, but i don't understand...Why `ContainerInterface` instead of `Container`?

Comment: That's just what Symfony injects when you tell it to inject the service container, it's part of the Symfony framework

Comment: but i don't understand Why ContainerInterface instead of Container

Comment: Say for example you have an application with 10 services that all inject the Symfony container, and pass `Container` to all of them.  But now you decide to extend the Symfony container and make your own with more functionality. Now you have to go back to those 10 services and change it to your class.  If you instead use ContainerInterface (which both the Symfony container and your extended container would implement), then you would't have to update any of your services.  Read more here (first lightbulb): http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html

Comment: Which aspect? Off the top of my head I feel like there shouldn't be much difference

Comment: Don't inject the service container, ever, use explicit arguments with DI instead.

Comment: Please re-read my post - I stated that it is not ideal but that in Symfony 2.3 it may not be avoidable, and that in Symfony 2.5 the error did not occur.

Answer (score 33):

Using constructor dependency injection (tested with Symfony 3.4):

```
class MyService
{
    private $mailer;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig_Environment $templating)
    {
        $this->mailer     = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function sendEmail()
    {
        $message = $this->templating->render('emails/registration.html.twig');

        // ...
    }
}
```

No need to configure arguments.

Comment: I get an error: `Uncaught Exception: Cannot resolve argument $mailer of "App\Controller\EmailController::send()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\EmailSender": argument "$template" of method "__construct()" has type "Twig_Environment" but this class was not found.`

Comment: Twig_Environment: `/** @deprecated since Twig 2.7, use "Twig\Environment" instead */`

Answer (score 7):

This works on Symfony +4.2, assuming your application's namespace is App and your mailer class service is named EmailService.

On your Service class:

```
// ...

private $mailer;
private $templating;

public function __construct( \Swift_Mailer $mailer, \Twig\Environment $templating )
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->templating = $templating;
}

public function sendEmailRegistration()
{
    $message = $this->templating->render('emails/registration.html.twig');

    // ...
}

// ...
```

On your services.yaml

```
services:
  email_service:
    class: App\Service\EmailService
    arguments: ['@swiftmailer.mailer.default', '@twig']
```